# How to get rid of margins in jquery layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am using [jquery layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/) and I have a very hard time getting rid of the margins on the panes. There is always a margin and no amount of css will get rid of them. I am implementing the simple demo.[simple demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/simple.html)
So basically I want the same thing but without any margins/padding on the inner panes. I'll adjust these my self. The objective is to be able to put a background image in there that stretches from border to border.

Hope I am clear enough.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the following CSS rule might fix your problem:

```
.ui-layout-pane {
  padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Unfortunately it looks like the pane plugin does a lot of absolute positioning and so it's likely the sizes of the containers will now be off by 20px each. You could write some jQuery to fix that, maybe:

```
jQuery('.ui-layout-pane').each( function() {
  var el = jQuery(this);
  el.width( el.width() + 20 );
} );
```

...or somesuch, but... yea, it's not ideal. You might want to look for a different plugin or modify the source of this one to account for the 20px discrepancy in the sizes of the panes.

Comment: To think I was sure I tried that dargn. Thanks!! I already resize everything so it didnt break anything at all. Ill accept your answer real soon it wont let me right now.

Comment: You can apply the `padding: 0px` inside the jQuery `each` function, directly to each pane elements. This solution works for me too.

Comment: @AndreasDietrich Does this answer no longer work? If it doesn't, you could update it. If it does, there's nothing wrong with it staying as is as an answer. Either way, no need to downvote.

Comment: @rfunduk I am sorry ... it was a mistake and I can't revoke my downvote, nor upvote as it still works and seems to be a good workaround. It was meant for another answer :-/ I deleted my previous comment so nobody gets confused. We could also delete this and your last comment to cleanup the comment section again :-/ sorry again

Comment: @AndreasDietrich Oh no worries, just for future reference :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using a newer version of UI Layout than when the O.P. created this question, but, I think this pane option has been around a little while. The following worked for me, and shouldn't require hacking (rather scouring the source / reading the docs)

Try setting applyDefaultStyles to false. (or maybe now it's called applyDemoStyles)

E.g.

```
$("body").layout({applyDefaultStyles:false});
```

or

```
$("body").layout({applyDemoStyles:false});
```

---

UPDATE:

FWIW - I'm using the [complex layout](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html)
 -- jquery.layout 1.3.0 - Release Candidate 30.79

Specifically, this worked for my "west sidebar" inner settings pane. 
For me, applyDefaultStyles controls the unwanted white padding for the pane I was targeting.
There are different ways to declare settings for the different panes.
I used 'list format' which looks like this...

```
//'list format'
westSidebarSettings_Inner = {
  applyDefaultStyles: false  // basic styling for testing & demo purposes
  , // (other settings ommitted in this stackoverflow snippet for brevity)
}

//'sub-key format'
var layoutSettings_Outer = {
  name: "outerLayout" 
  // options.defaults apply to ALL PANES - but overridden by pane-specific settings
 , defaults: {
    size: "auto"
    , minSize: 50
    , paneClass: "pane"         // default = 'ui-layout-pane'
    , resizerClass: "resizer"   // default = 'ui-layout-resizer'
    , togglerClass: "toggler"   // default = 'ui-layout-toggler'
    , buttonClass: "button" // default = 'ui-layout-button'
  }
 , north: {
    spacing_open: 21                // cosmetic spacing
    , togglerLength_open: 21        // to HIDE the toggler button, set = 0
    , togglerLength_closed: 21      // "100%" OR -1 = full width of pane
  }
}


$(document).ready(function () {
  // create the OUTER LAYOUT
  outerLayout = $("body").layout(layoutSettings_Outer);

  // create an INNER LAYOUT to split my west sidebar into 2 pieces 
  // (actual settings ommitted in this stackoverflow snippet for brevity)
  innerLayout = $(outerLayout.options.west.paneSelector).layout(westSidebarSettings_Inner);
});
```

Comment: what version of layout are you using? I'll update my answer above with my specific findings.

Comment: the complex layout sample.. is indeed.. complex. but, I can say I've tested and this indeed works for me.